# python recursion function that takes two inputs

Tags: python, recursion

I am new to python and I am having a problem. I want to write a recursive function that takes two inputs (integers) and subtracts the second from the first, until the first is less than the second, and calculates the # of time it subtracts before being less.

This is what I have so far, but I am having problems getting the function to repeat the subtraction of the second from the first;

```
def div(first,sec):
    if first > sec:
        return div((first - sec),sec) + first

    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: I don't see a recursive call in that function. Get rid of the `while` loop and put in a recursive call instead.

Comment: I don't understand why this has been rated down...

Comment: i changed it to what i had initially, I can do it using a single input  but i don't really understand the multiple input.

Comment: You mean 'until the first is less than the second', right?

Comment: yes that's what I meant, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
## naive recursion
def div(a, b):
    if (a >= b):
        return div(a - b, b) + 1
    else: return 0

try:
    print div(5678, 3)
except Exception as e:
    print e  ## maximum recursion depth exceeded


## less naive recursion with trampolines
## see https://gist.github.com/802557 for details/explanations
def trampoline(f):
    def _(*args):
        result = f(*args)
        while callable(result):
            result = result()
        return result
    return _

def div_func(a, b, acc=0):
    if (a >= b):
        return lambda: div_func(a - b, b, acc + 1)
    else: return acc

div2 = trampoline(div_func)

## ok
print div2(5678, 3)
```

Comment: the last few I don't understand, since I am a newbie, however the first works fine. if you don't could you give a brief explanation as to how the code works? @thg435

Comment: The first snippet is the same as others already posted. The second one uses a [trampoline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_%28computers%29) to eliminate [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). The main idea of this method is that a recursive function, instead of calling itself directly, returns this call "closed" in a temporary function.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like that?

```
def div(first,second):
    if (first >= second):
        return div(first-second,second) + 1
    else: return 0
```

But you'll run into problem when trying `div(100000,3)` for example, because the recursion i too deep. To avoid that, you can simply do:

```
first/second
```

Comment: If you try my approach, you don't have any problem while trying `div(100000,3)`!
+1 because of your solution `first/second`: yes, it is simple like that (if `first` and `second` are `int`)!

Comment: but it's not recursive @india_dourada. I but it is more useful though.

Comment: @zenpoy What if instead of returning the number of times it was subtracted i wanted to return the value of the first after subtracting the second until it is less than the first is less, how would i go about doing that?

Comment: try this: `def div(first,second, lista): if (first >= second): lista.append(first-second) div(first-second, second, lista) return lista` then you have to create an empty list `listb = []` and call the function `a = div(565,34, listb)`  `listb` will contain the values of the first after subtracting the second until it is less than it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do what you want:

```
def div(first, sec):
    if first >= sec:
        return div(first - sec, sec) + 1
    else:
        return 0

>>> div(6, 2)
3
>>> div(8, 4)
2
>>> div(12, 2)
6
```

Here is the call chain for `div(6, 2)`, which may help you understand how this works:

```
div(6, 2) == 1 + div(4, 2)
          == 1 + 1 + div(2, 2)
          == 1 + 1 + 1 + div(0, 2)
          == 1 + 1 + 1 + 0
```

Comment: yes it works perfectly, thanks. can I have brief explanation of how it works?

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want. You don't need an `if` function, but a `while` one!

```
# function:
def div(a,b):
    count = 0
    while a > b:
        a = a - b
        count = count + 1
return count

# now we'll use the function:
a = div(565,34)
b = div(34,565)
```

a will be 16, and b will be 0!

Comment: sorry, this is not recursive!